# How to prove some formulations aboult Kronecker product?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra, kronecker-product

The Kronecker product has some properties as the wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product.

For the sake of simplicity, we denote $\mathbf{U}_{M}^T\otimes \cdots\mathbf{U}_{m+1}^T\otimes \mathbf{U}_{m-1}^T\otimes\cdots\otimes \mathbf{U}_{1}^T$ as $\bigotimes_{k=M,k\neq m}^{1}\mathbf{U}_{k}^T$, where $\mathbf{U}_k\in \mathbb{R}^{I_k\times J_k}$.

Could anyone prove the following fomulations?
$$
\bigotimes_{k=M,k\neq m}^{1}\mathbf{U}_{k}^T=\bigotimes_{k=1,k\neq m}^{M}\mathbf{U}_{k}^T
$$
$$
\left(\bigotimes_{k=1,k\neq m}^{M}\mathbf{U}_{k}^T\right)^T=\bigotimes_{k=1,k\neq m}^{M}\mathbf{U}_{k}
$$

Comment: The second formula is true, but the first one is not since the kronecker product is not generally commutative.  For example, take
$$
U_1 = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}, \quad
U_3 = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}\\
U_1^T \otimes U_3^T = 
\pmatrix{
1&1&0&0\\
1&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&1
}\neq
U_3^T \otimes U_1^T = 
\pmatrix{
1&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&1\\
1&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&1
}
$$

Comment: Thanks! You are right! Can you help another problem about multilinear algebra "How to prove the formulation of mode-$n$ matricization and preclusive mode-$n$ product?"

Comment: I'll take a look. Are you still looking for a proof of the second formula here?

Comment: Yes, I have a simple idea. $(A\otimes B)^T=A^T\otimes B^T$, can substituting for proof. Is it ture?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but if you mean what I think you do then yes, your proof should work.

Comment: $\left(\bigotimes_{k=1,k\neq m}^{M}\mathbf{U}_k^T\right)^T=\left(\bigotimes_{k=1,k\neq m}^{M-1}\mathbf{U}_k^T\right)^T\otimes \mathbf{U}_M=\ldots=\bigotimes_{k=1,k\neq m}^{M}\mathbf{U}_k$. Does it work?

Comment: Oh... yes, that's what I had in mind.  That's fine.

Comment: Thanks! Please help me another problem at your convenience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof:

The first formula is false.
$$
\mathbf{U}_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\mathbf{U}_3=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\mathbf{U}_1^T\otimes \mathbf{U}_3^T \neq \mathbf{U}_3^T\otimes \mathbf{U}_1^T
$$
The second formula is proven as follows:
$$
\left(\bigotimes_{k=1,k\neq m}^{M}\mathbf{U}_k^T\right)^T=\left(\bigotimes_{k=1,k\neq m}^{M-1}\mathbf{U}_k^T\right)^T\otimes \mathbf{U}_M=\ldots=\otimes_{k=1,k\neq m}^{M}\mathbf{U}_k
$$